# Create a “Open” Dialog Button and get the the file name with extension .dat

Tags: c#

I want to create a browse (**OpenFile Dialog**) `Button` to search my local drive and then write out the selected file name (not the full path ) to a `TextBox`. It should show Only **.dat** extension files.

I am using Visual Studio 2008

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: This is not the way to ask questions on StackOverflow.
See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Do you want your custom OpenFile dialog ??

Comment: SO require more effort to reward you with best answers

Answer (score 1):

Next time you ask anything, show some examples of what you have tried please.

```
private string GetDatFileName()
{
     // Create Open File Dialog with the correct filter
     using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()) {
         ofd.Filter = "dat-file (*.dat) | *.dat";

         string fileNameAndFolder = "";
         string fileName = "";

         // Get file plus folder.
         if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             fileNameAndFolder = ofd.FileName;

             // Split folder and filename
             fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileNameAndFolder);
         }

         // Return the fileName;
         return fileName;
     }
}
```

What I have done here is create an `OpenFileDialog` and set its filter to the required "dat"-format. Only `.dat-files` will show up in the browserdialog.

Next, you show the dialog and check if the result is OK. If the result is, you will get the full filename (with folder) into a variable. All thats left then, is to get the filename from  fileNameAndFolder.

Comment: Thank you for that using statement, I had indeed forgotten that!

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you should reward lazy askers with an answer. This may give the feeling to other lazy askers that they can get away with it anyway. The comment of Zohar Peled is the correct reaction to questions like these.

Comment: While I get the ethics-part in the fact that I should not reward lazy askers with an answer, I do think that seeing the actual code can help them further into learning and understanding programming. That may be going out of good nature and faith in human beings, I acknowledge that, but I guess that is just one of my shortcomings then.

Comment: Instead of parsing the file name manually, wouldn't it be easier (safer?) to use [`Path.GetFileName(fileNameAndFolder)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead? EDIT: Oh wait, this is kinda weird code about attempting to parse it out on an empty string because of a cancelled dialogue; I think it will still work though.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I didn't even know about the GetFileName. Works perfectly, also if the dialogresult is not OK, an empty string will not give any errors. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @Matthijs: No, it won't give any errors. But it seems incorrect to me to be parsing for a file name in any case _except_ for when the user successfully chooses a file. If the method is to return an empty string on a cancelled dialogue, that's fine, but I'd suggest that the file name parsing (`Path.GetFileName`) occur _only_ within the `if` block.